# Remove both words from string with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove 2 words from a string. The words are `_with` and `_and` so `raised_hand_with_fingers_and_splayed` becomes `raised_hand_fingers_splayed`

The regex `/_with|_and/` appears to work in https://regexr.com/ but when I use it with JavaScript only the `_with` is removed:

```
const str = `raised_hand_with_fingers_and_splayed`;
const newStr = str.replace(/_with|_and/,"")
```

Comment: You missed the global flag `g` that regexr includes by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `g` modifier to perform multiple replacements. Otherwise it just replaces the first match.

```js
const str = `raised_hand_with_fingers_and_splayed`;
const newStr = str.replace(/_with|_and/g,"")
console.log(newStr);
```